# how can I setState in unmount Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, unmount

How can we setState in `componentDidMount` hook within an argument?

My problem is the warning of React notify that:

```
Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted 
component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your 
application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the 
componentWillUnmount method.
in DiscoverPage (created by Route)
```

In my `DiscoverPage` component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import TvShows from './TvShows';
import Movies from './Movies';
import MovieDetail from "../MoviePage/MovieDetail";
import TvDetail from "../TvShowPage/TvDetail";

class DiscoverPage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {}
    }
  }

  getDataItem = (data) => {
    this.setState({ data: data });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/discover/movie" render={props => <Movies data={this.getDataItem} {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/discover/tv" render={props => <TvShows data={this.getDataItem} {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/movie/:movie" render={props => <MovieDetail data={this.state.data} {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/tv/:tv" render={props => <TvDetail data={this.state.data} {...props} />} />
        <Redirect to="/discover/movie" />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}

export default DiscoverPage;
```

In Child component (this case is `Movies` component):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import requestApi from '../api';
import MovieList from "../MoviePage/MovieList";

class Movies extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {
        page: 1,
        results: []
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    requestApi.fetchData('discover', 'movie').then(response => {
      this.setState({ data: response.data, isLoading: false });
    });
  }

  getMoviebyId = (id) => {
    requestApi.fetchDataById('movie', id).then(response => {
      this.props.data(response.data);
    });
  };

  nextPage = (e) => {
    const page = this.state.data.page + 1;
    requestApi.fetchDataPaginate('discover', 'movie', page).then(response => {
      this.setState({ data: response.data });
    });
  };
  prevPaginate = (e) => {
    const page = this.state.data.page - 1;
    requestApi.fetchDataPaginate('discover', 'movie', page).then(response => {
      this.setState({ data: response.data });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="ss_media">
          <h2 className="title">Discover New Movies & TV Shows</h2>
          <MovieList
            movie={this.getMoviebyId}
            routeProps={this.props}
            prevPaginate={this.prevPaginate}
            nextPaginate={this.nextPage}
            moviesList={this.state.data} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Movies;
```

Comment: It looks a little bit strange. `getDataItem` method sets new state. Just to be clear, do you expect `getDataItem` set new state instead of returning `state.data`?

Comment: hi @MikhailKatrin, getDataItem is a callback function. when Movies component creates a AJAX request then pass data to the parent (this case is DiscoverPage), and then parent component (DiscoverPage) will receive data and set to base state.

Comment: can you show how do you call `getDataItem` from within any child component?

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan I was updated more information. Please check above. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you're getting is telling you that you can't call `setState` on an unmounted component, i.e. a component that's not currently rendered. Most likely, one of your other components (`Movies`, `TvShows`, etc.) is calling the method you pass as the `data` prop. When one of these components is rendered, the `DiscoveryPage` component is not, so calling the `getDataItem` through the `data` prop will result in `DiscoveryPage`'s `setState` method to be called, when it's not rendered. To fix this (assuming that what you want to do is pass data from component to component) I'd suggest maybe using `localStorage` to store a shared variable (or, as @Anu suggested, some other kind of store).

I don't understand what you mean about "in arguments", but, answering your question, you can call `setState` in any `component...` method (even though calling it in `componentWillUnmount` makes little to no sense, since this methos is only called when the component is about to be unmounted).

EDIT:
Look at the `Movie` component. Using `localStorage` as our store, in the `getMovieById` method, instead of:

```
getMoviebyId = (id) => {
    requestApi.fetchDataById('movie', id).then(response => {
        //this next sentence will call DiscoveryPage's setState
        //DiscoveryPage is not mounted, so a warning will be raised
        this.props.data(response.data);
    });
};
```

you could have something like:

```
getMoviebyId = (id) => {
    requestApi.fetchDataById('movie', id).then(response => {
        //any component can access this store
        localStorage.setItem("data", response.data);
    });
};
```

and then, in some other component, or method, access it like so:

```
localStorage.getItem("data");
```

Your code is a little bit confusing. I'm having a little trouble understanding where you're using the `DiscoveryPage`'s `data`, the one you're setting when you call the `data` method. But anyway, hope this helps.

Just one more side note: When using `localStorage`, it's good practice to manage it, by which I mean calling `localStorage.removeItem("data")` when you're done using the `data` value. This is best done, for example, in some `componentWillUnmount` method.

Comment: Thank you!. Its work, but more questions are where should I put `localStorage` in my component. I put it in `componentDidMount` and it works very well.

I also unsubscribed it by add this hook.

`componentWillUnmount() {
        localStorage.removeItem("data");
    }`

it fine?

Comment: Glad to hear! :) yes, that was the approach I was suggesting. Just take care not to remove it while you still need it in another component. Try figuring out a way of having a parent component for the components that need it, and managing it there. Also bear in mind that this is, IHMO, an error-prone pattern, so I also recommend considering other ways of managing stores, e.g. react-redux.

Answer (score 2):

Your DiscoverPage component unmounts when the route changes and after that your invoking getDataItem method. This is why react is throwing error.

I would suggest to use react-router component method instead of render and moving the data to a store which can then be accessed by any component. Refer [react-router render methods](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/route-render-methods)

Example:

```
<Route path="/user/:username" component={User}/>
```

Comment: Yeah, but how can I pass one of these props to component by this way?

Comment: @PhuongThuan You can save the data in the store instead of passing props.

Comment: @PhuongThuan if you follow the pattern that Anu is suggesting, you wouldn't pass the data through props. Instead, you'd access it in a store. Any given component could read and write this value, so that every component had the same data (which is logically similar to what I think you're trying to do).

Comment: @Anu how can I using react-router-component instead of render func but still pass props to Child. and somehow child will receive props from parent?

Comment: @PhuongThuan Are you using some state management library like redux in your app?

Comment: @Anu, no i only use pure react, not redux or flux or mobx.
i write Route like this: 
`<Route path="/movie/:movie" component={MovieDetail} data={this.state.data} />`

it should be ok?

Answer (score 1):

Some changes need to be done ,the logic you are using is not efficient
ass much as I understood from your question that would be good

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import TvShows from './TvShows';
import Movies from './Movies';
import MovieDetail from '../MoviePage/MovieDetail';
import TvDetail from '../TvShowPage/TvDetail';

class DiscoverPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: {}
        };
    }
    getALLDATA() {
        //update your state after your request
        request().then(res => {
            this.setState({
                data: res.data
            });
        });
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getALLDATA();
    }
    getDataItem = () => {
        return this.state.data;
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/discover/movie" render={props => <Movies data={this.getDataItem} {...props} />} />
                <Route path="/discover/tv" render={props => <TvShows data={this.getDataItem} {...props} />} />
                <Route path="/movie/:movie" render={props => <MovieDetail data={this.state.data} {...props} />} />
                <Route path="/tv/:tv" render={props => <TvDetail data={this.state.data} {...props} />} />
                <Redirect to="/discover/movie" />
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}

export default DiscoverPage;
```

Comment: my getDataItem function accepts one parameter. I was called AJAX request in Movies component then pass the result to parent Component (this case is DiscoverPage )

Comment: logically you should do the inverse , you should get the data in parent and pass them to the children anw if that what you wish try 
<TvShows data={this.getDataItem.bind(this)}

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to import **BrowserRouter** from `react-router-dom`

```
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; // Add BrowserRouter

class DiscoverPage extends Component {

...
render() {
    return (
    <BrowserRouter> // Add this 
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/discover/movie" render={props => <Movies data={this.getDataItem} {...props} />} />
            <Route path="/discover/tv" render={props => <TvShows data={this.getDataItem} {...props} />} />
            <Route path="/movie/:movie" render={props => <MovieDetail data={this.state.data} {...props} />} />
            <Route path="/tv/:tv" render={props => <TvDetail data={this.state.data} {...props} />} />
            <Redirect to="/discover/movie" />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: I was added BrowserRouter in App component.

Answer (score 0):

We can set state in **componentDidMount** like:

```
componentDidMount(){
    var {state, setState} = this.props;
    setState({doNotRender: true});
}
```

But instead use **componentDidUpdate** like:

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    var {state, setState} = this.props;
    if(!state.doNotRender){ //any_condition ur choice
       setState({doNotRender: true});
    }
}
```